# REST API resource structure where there are multiple "owners"

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture, restful-url

I am struggling to see how to structure a REST API where multiple owners may use the same resource. For example if there are `users` and `organizations` and each of them has something like `images` or `locations`. An Image and a location is a database field, which is the same for both users and organizations... I can see two basic ways to go about it

## Separate endpoints:

```
POST /users/:userID/documents
GET /users/:userID/documents/:id
POST /org/:orgID/documents
GET /org/:orgID/documents/:id
```

**pros of separate endpoints:** The logic is clean and everything is very obvious

**cons of separate endpoints:** There is a LOT of code copying between the endpoints.

Shared endpoints:

```
POST /documents
GET /documents/:id
```

**pros of separate endpoints:** There are fewer overall endpoints, less code copying.

**cons of separate endpoints:** The logic gets messy, IDK the best way to go about sending the `orgID` or `userID` with the request (without in effect creating a new endpoint within the `/documents` resource. I could use a query string, but that just feels wrong... (IDK if it is wrong)

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the use case scenarios for your API.

There's nothing wrong with separate endpoints, if the flow would generally be to request users/organizations and their respective documents. It also doesn't have to mean code duplication - you can simply have some sort of common DocumentRepository in the backend, consumed in multiple places.

However, if the requirements are to simply search/display documents, a query string might be your best bet:

```
GET /documents?userId={userId}&organizationId={organizationId}
```